# Triangular shaped dividers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, user-experience

How can I make triangular shaped dividers in MaterialUI like in the exemple bellow?

[image]

Comment: Use an SVG element?

Comment: There will need to be a photo element integrated into the shape in transparency and additionally a button, don't think svg is a solution. Could be rong..

Comment: The photo doesn't need to be in the SVG? only the white part does

Comment: Understood. Will try thank you :)